# How to reuse CALayer

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, calayer

I want to use a `CAGradientLayer` for each of the cell backgrounds in a custom table scroll view. If I allocate a `CAGradientLayer` for each cell, scrolling is slow, so I would like to somehow reuse the gradient for each cell, sort of how you can reuse the `UIImage` in a `UIImageView`. Is such a thing possible?

```
gradient = [CAGradientLayer new];
        gradient.frame = innerView.bounds;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
        //gradient.shouldRasterize = YES;
    [innerView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom table scroll view? Is it a UITableView, UIScrollView, UIView? How custom are we talking? If it's a UITableView and you make use of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: you should only have the gradient layers for the visible cells and they won't be created anew for each cell while scrolling.

Comment: It is basically a scroll view with UIView cells inside. The background of the these cells is what I'm trying to put the gradient on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I could simply render the gradient (`renderInContext:`) into a context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` and reuse the image obtained from it.